# Best way to handle summary data and detailed data

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql

I am building a dashboard app and a data analytics app.  I have Python on the web server, which extracts records from Postgres.  An example can be found at ohba.io, or http://www.ohba.io/sample1_dashboard/. Most of my dashboard visualizations show summary or aggregated data.  I do the summarization in either Postgres or Pandas on the web server.

Now, someone wants to drill down and see all invoices for any given sales rep.

My questions has to do with the amount of data and how to send it to the individual web users. I see several options:

1. Send the all invoices for all sales reps- I don't like this option.
2. Let the user select a sales rep, have the JavaScript on the local computer send a request to the Python server which executes a Postgres select for that sales rep, and then python sends the data back to java script on the local computer.  - that seems tedious but doable.

Or, is there a third way to have JavaScript securely quiz the Postgres server?

I have no experience in this, and would greatly appreciate all advice and thoughts.  If there are any samples of code, that would help.

James

Comment: a strategy I like, and is implemented by some BI tools, is to provide a custom report that should be generated if a user needs to drill-down. An improvement on this is to code in several such drill down reports that the user might use based on permissions policy and need.

Comment: I would prefer your option 2. With option 1, you may end up in a scenario where the detail data is too big and results in the dashboard loading slowly, or the detail data is something the user should not have access to.